# SharePoint 2013. "Request failed. List does not exist at site with URL 'http://sharepnt13'."

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

I am getting this pop up when clicking add new item to a list from a web part that lives on a site page. I am able to add the new item and it saves fine and even appears on the web part. I am unsure what is causing this pop-up but it doesn't seem to negatively effect anything. [image]

Comment: 'Apps Call Log' is your SharePoint list?

Comment: 'Apps Log" is the current name it was called 'Apps Call Log'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have created a new list from list template that has a lookup column from another list `"Apps Call Log"` that already not exist in your current site.

**So to overcome this issue:**

- Go to list setting.
- Try to update the lookup column with a field from a list already exist in the current site.
- Or create `"Apps Call Log"` list in the current site and refresh lookup column in your main list.

**Note:** Also Make sure that the current site page is live on the your site

Comment: So there is no lookup column in "Apps Log". "Apps Call Log" is just the name of the page. However "Apps Log" used to be called "Apps Call Log" I wonder if that had something to do with it.

Comment: How you added your list to your page ? also it mntone in message there is list name called Apps Call Log !!

Comment: Its just a web part on the page. not currently no, there is no list called "Apps Call Log"

Comment: Okay because you have renamed your list from Apps Call Log to Apps Call, may be it will need to refresh your page by editing it then add your list again

Comment: Tried that, nothing changed.

Comment: add your list to a new page

Comment: still get the same error